# JavaFX: make a vertical ScrollBar fit to parent node in TableView

Tags: java, css, javafx

I have a TableView that scrolls vertically, and I would like the ScrollBar to extend to the top of it's parent AnchorPane and to be on top of the filler square at the top right. See below for what it's like by default. Note that my filler node is white, that is not a table column at the top right.

[image]

and below this line is what I want, correctly implemented by another program.

[image]

I was able to achieve this by doing

```
Platform.runLater(() ->
{
    ScrollBar someScrollBar = (ScrollBar) someTable.lookup(".scroll-bar:vertical");
    someScrollBar.setTranslateY(-12);
    someScrollBar.setScaleY(1.2);
}
);
```

where `someTable` is a TableView made in FXML and is referred to in the controller initialize function.

[image]

It looks fine like this, but it doesn't scale correctly. If the containing AnchorPane resizes vertically, it looks awful.

Can anyone suggest a better way to do this?

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: you need a custom TableViewSkin with a custom TableHeaderRow: the latter is responsible for managing the .. well, tableHeader :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Custom layout of the scrollBars is not supported. And my initial comment *you need a custom TableViewSkin with a custom TableHeaderRow: the latter is responsible for managing the .. well, tableHeader* is only part of the story, unfortunately.

- a TableHeaderRow indeed is responsible for laying out the table header
- but: a TableHeaderRow can do nothing to layout the vertical scrollbar - when it tries to do so in an overridden `layoutChildren()` it's immediately reset
- the reset happens in the VirtualFlow (which is the parent of the scrollBar)

So at the end of the day, we need

- a custom TableHeaderRow that signals the need for enlarging and relocating the scrollBar: the example below sets a marker if the scrollBar is visible (tbd: check whether or not the menuButton is visible) with the desired additional height in the scrollBar's properties map
- a custom VirtualFlow that can handle the marker and actually does the layout as needed: the example below checks for the marker and resizes/relocates the scrollBar if needed.
- a custom TableViewSkin to inject both (via overridden factory methods)

The example is written against fx11, should work for fx10 but not for fx9 because the latter doesn't allow to provide a custom VirtualFlow:

```
public class TableWithoutCorner extends Application {

    /**
     * Custom TableHeaderRow that requests a larger vbar height
     * if needed.
     */
    private static class MyTableHeader extends TableHeaderRow {

        private Region cornerAlias;
        private ScrollBar vBar;
        private TableViewSkinBase skin;

        public MyTableHeader(TableViewSkinBase skin) {
            super(skin);
            this.skin = skin;
        }

        @Override
        protected void layoutChildren() {
            super.layoutChildren();
            adjustCornerLayout();
        }

        private void adjustCornerLayout() {
            checkAlias();
            // tbd: check also if corner is visible
            if (!vBar.isVisible()) {
                vBar.getProperties().remove("DELTA");
            } else { 
                vBar.getProperties().put("DELTA", getHeight());
            }
        }

        private void checkAlias() {
            if (cornerAlias == null) {
                cornerAlias = (Region) lookup(".show-hide-columns-button");
            }
            if (vBar == null) {
                vBar = (ScrollBar) skin.getSkinnable().lookup(".scroll-bar:vertical");
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Custom VirtualFlow that respects additinal height for its 
     * vertical ScrollBar.
     */
    private static class MyFlow extends VirtualFlow {

        private ScrollBar vBar;
        private Region clip;

        public MyFlow() {
            // the scrollbar to adjust
            vBar = (ScrollBar) lookup(".scroll-bar:vertical");
            // the clipped container to use for accessing viewport dimensions
            clip = (Region) lookup(".clipped-container");

        }

        /**
         * Overridden to adjust vertical scrollbar's height and y-location
         * after calling super.
         */
        @Override
        protected void layoutChildren() {
            super.layoutChildren();
            adjustVBar();
        }

        /**
         * Adjusts vBar height and y-location by the height as
         * requested by the table header.
         */
        protected void adjustVBar() {
            if (vBar.getProperties().get("DELTA") == null) return;
            double delta = (double) vBar.getProperties().get("DELTA");
            vBar.relocate(clip.getWidth(), - delta);
            vBar.resize(vBar.getWidth(), clip.getHeight() + delta);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Boilerplate: need custom TableViewSkin to inject a custom TableHeaderRow and
     * custom VirtualFlow.
     */
    private static class MyTableViewSkin<T> extends TableViewSkin<T> {

        public MyTableViewSkin(TableView<T> control) {
            super(control);
        }

        @Override
        protected TableHeaderRow createTableHeaderRow() {
            return new MyTableHeader(this);
        }

        @Override
        protected VirtualFlow<TableRow<T>> createVirtualFlow() {
            return new MyFlow();
        }

    }

    private Parent createContent() {
        TableView<Locale> table = new TableView<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(Locale.getAvailableLocales())) {

            @Override
            protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() {
                return new MyTableViewSkin(this);
            }

        }; 
        TableColumn<Locale, String> col = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        col.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("displayName"));
        table.getColumns().addAll(col);
        return table;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setScene(new Scene(createContent()));
        //stage.setTitle(FXUtils.version());
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger
            .getLogger(TableWithoutCorner.class.getName());

}
```